Want to stop auto translating of my Gmail
I email regularly in Polish, though I have English language laptop and PC. Never had a problem writing in Polish. Today I drafted an email and Gmail insists on translating my Polish text into English. How can I stop this from happening? Mostly I do write in English, but I email in Finnish, French and Polish from time to time. I WANT those texts in the language I first wrote them -- always!

Welcome to [webapps.se]. AFAIK that is not a built-in function in Gmail. Does this happens if you compose a message using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled? What operating system and web browser do you normally use? (please [edit] the question to clarify this)

It is a built-in feature of Gmail itself, so the question should be reopened.
